# Can I do case when the last 3 string equal aaa then do...?

Tags: sql, case

I have a string of data and I'd like to see if I can do a case when statement if it endings in certain texts then return value from different temporary table. Is it possible to do this?
i.e. case when prodwarehouse ending in '001' then pull the on hand qty from table #a else 0 end.
     case when prodwarehouse ending in '009' then pull from on hand qty from table #b else 0 end.

Table #a and #b has those values : productwarehouse - on hand qty

Comment: I just found out i can still do %string% with case when, I'll try that. But can we pull the certain values from those tables #a or #b based on the case when criteria?

Comment: like statements are not always the fastest.  Right(field,3) will work in some databases...what database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know much about how many tables are involved or the relationsships but you can use case statements with a sub select.

```
select 
  case when prodwarehouse like '%001' then (select onHandQty from tableA a where yt.id = a.id) 
       when prodwarehouse like '%009' then (select onHandQty from tableB b where yt.id = b.id)
       else 0
  end as 'Qty'
from yourTable yt
```

OR you could just join the tables so that you wouldn't need to do a sub select.

```
select 
  case when a.prodwarehouse like '%001' then b.qty
       when a.prodwarehouse like '%009' then c.qty
       else 0
  end as 'Qty'
from tablea a
join table b on...
join table c on...
```

Comment: @user3508386 Please mark this as the answer if it worked for you.